# VueJS Use prop as data-attribute value

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

I am really struggling with the following scenario:

Some index page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">

      <ul>
        <li>some existing option</li>
        <example-component :foo="foo" :bar="bar"/>
      </ul>

      <a @click.prevent="showDetail(1, 'abc')" href="#" >Click ME!</a>

    </div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Some single file component:

```
<template>
    <li><a v-show="checkBool" data-toggle="tab" class="some-class" href="#container-div" data-tab-url="{{ this.foo }}">{{ this.bar }}</a></li>
</template>



<script>
export default {

  props: ['foo', 'bar'],


  computed: {
    checkBool: function() {
      return (this.foo != undefined && this.bar != undefined )
    }

  }

}
</script>
```

And the `app.js` looks something like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.component('example-component', require('ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    props: [
      'foo',
      'bar'
    ],

    data: {
      foo: '',
      bar: ''
    },

     methods: {
      showDetail: function (foo, bar) {
        this.foo = foo,
        this.bar = bar
      }
  }
});
```

I am using babel with webpack under a laravel instalation.

The scenario is like this:

- When I click the `Click ME!` link, `foo` and `bar` are updated and passed to the component (This part is working)
- The computed property, named `checkBool` for this example becomes true, so I will then see the new list item (This part is working)
- New list item, has a link, with the text correctly set to `bar` (This part is also working)

At this point I know that the values setting and communication between component and parent is working properly, however `data-tab-url="{{ this.foo }}"` part is driving me crazy.

Instead of parsing the moustache syntax as expected and return `data-tab-url="1"`, I get a parsed/escaped value of everything between quotes.

Something like `data-tab-url="%7B%7B+this.foo+%7D%7D"`.

Now, how do I prevent the encode from happening?
From what I've read, there used to be a way in `vuejs 1.*`. Using three brackets: `{{{ this.foo }}}` but it's now deprecated in favor of `v-html` which I cannot use for my example.

Comment: If you use Vue in development mode you should see some warnings in your browser console.
You should'nt use props in Vue instance - so in `new Vue({...})`.
Here you declare `foo` and `bar` in `props` and `data` so there is a conflict.
You should use data in a Vue instance and use data as a function (because you must declare function for data in component https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data see Restriction. So do it everywhere to not be surprise one day ) :
`data: function() {
   return {
      foo: '',
      bar: ''
   }
}`

Comment: Remove `props: [
      'foo',
      'bar'
    ],`  in app.js should do the job.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Actually, I only have the `props` and don't have the `data` at all in the main `Vue`

Comment: Ok and all is fine now ? Everything works as expected ? ( I thought you have an other problem... so sorry if it not the case...)

Comment: I do have a Huge understanding problem concerning VueJS and Jquery, playing nice together. VueJS is always one step behind Jquery.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Bind the attribute like this `:data-tab-url="foo"`.

This will give the affected element a `data-tab-url` attribute with a value equal to the `foo` property of your component.

Answer (score 10):

thanksd's answer is right but;

for further understanding:

You can't use mustache syntax for attribute binding. Use mustache {{}} only content of a dom element, ie.

```
 <div>{{someValue}}</div> (THIS IS WRONG)
```

To bind any attribute, including template props any other attribute, such as "src" or "data-tab-url" like in question, you can use "v-bind:attr" or ":attr" shorthand, ie.

```
 <div v-bind:src="someDataVariable"></div>
```

or

```
<div v-bind:some-prop="someMethod()"></div>
```

You can use any member(data, method, computed etc.) of your component or Vue app, without "this".

Answer (score 1):

To render any component instance property (prop, data, computed ...) inside html you've to :

- Bind it to an attribute using `v-bind:` or the shorthand `:` like `:foo="someFoo"`
- Use it inside mustache syntax `{{someFoo}}`
- Use it as directive value `v-show="isShown"` or `v-model="username"`, directives are always prefixed by `v-`

For the events, they are written like `v-on:eventName` or `@eventName` which could run an inline statement `@click="count++"` or a method `@click="increment"` knowing that `increment` is a function defined inside the `methods` options