# How to display full message in title attribute?

Tags: html

I want to display a full message in the title (or tooltip).

This is a part of the table that I want to make it display the full message (I have to set overflow style to **td** in **css** file, so it will not display a full message if the message is too long).

```
<template v-for="val in data_from_database">
  <tr>
    ...
    <td title="{{val.name}}">   <!-- This one only shows {{val.name}} -->
      {{val.name}}              <!-- This one works normally -->
    </td>
    ...
  </tr>
</template>
```

But the problem is title attribute only treats its value as a normal string. In this case, it will only display on the tooltip as `{{val.name}}` instead of the value of `val.name` (in this case, it is the project name in the database).

Note that `val.name` in the table content works normally (It shows the project name as I want)
[This is what it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luQqj.png)

Comment: Use :title="val.name" instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS Use prop as data-attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236848/vuejs-use-prop-as-data-attribute-value)

Comment: Adding ':' before title works, thank you! @Wimanicesir